# Get the SID of a Linux computer joined to a windows AD domain

Tags: linux, active-directory

With realmd you can integrate Linux servers into AD much easier. It sets up SSSD and Kerberos locally, and it creates all of the necessary objects in AD.

Now I search for a command I can run on the linux box's terminal to get the SID (Security Identifier) assigned to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the SID you can simply use the `realm` command like this `realm list --machine`

It will give you the machine domain name information and the associated SID

Comment: Hey @saxtheowl, I do not have a setup (yet) but I couldn’t find the `—machine` argument in the man page. Do you have a reference? A screenshot of the command with output (redacted sensitiv content)?

Comment: Try with realm discover <domain_name> domain_name being your Windows AD domain